# Powershell command for Excel Services? 

Tags: powershell, excel-services

Is there a powershell to restart the excel services? If yes, what is the syntax to restart the excel services.

Comment: Our excel services seem to be not working and only thing I read or heard is to delete existing one and provision a new excel service. I hope I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service instance is not online, you can use the following PowerShell syntax:
Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -match "Excel"} | Start-SPServiceInstance